# Why is the "at" command on Windows XP not behaving as expected?

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

On Windows XP I'm trying to add a job like this:

```
at 17:07 /every:s dir
```

I expect `dir` to be executed every Saturday at 17:07, however I don't see anything happens in the command line window.

Here is the log:

```
D:\temp>at 17:07 /every:s dir
Added a new job with job ID = 1

D:\temp>time/t
05:06 PM

D:\temp>date/t
Sat 10/02/2010

D:\temp>at
Status ID   Day                     Time          Command Line
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error   1   Each S                  5:07 PM       dir

D:\temp>time/t
05:08 PM

D:\temp>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: AT.EXE is only included for backwards compatibility with NT4.  Use SCHTASKS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Microsoft documentation page for the '`at`' command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true),

> To run a command that is not an executable (that is, `.exe`) file,
>   precede the command with cmd /c to load Cmd.exe as follows:

```
cmd /c dir > c:\test.out
```

Also as their example shows,
if you want the '`dir`' output to be usable, you should redirect it to some file.

---

Further, like the comment on your question describes, the documentation page notes,

> [Schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx) is a more powerful superset command-line scheduling tool and includes all the functionality found in the '`at`' command-line utility. Use schtasks instead of at for all command-line scheduling tasks.